# How can I set a default header for all the HTTP requests using DelegatingHandler middlewhare?

Tags: c#, .net, dotnet-httpclient, asp.net-core-middleware

I use a middleware for an `HttpClient`. I use one instance of `HttpClient` as a singleton (we don't use DI, otherwise an `HttpClientFactory` would be a better option).

My question:
Is it possible to set a default header for all the requests inside `MyCustomHandler`? I want to implement the logic of checking this header during the very first request and setting for ALL future requests.

```
public class MyCustomHandler : DelegatingHandler
{

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // Here, I want to add logic to check if a specific header exists
        // (in my case, Authorization), and if it does not exist, set this header
        // as the default for all future requests.
    }
}
```

I've already tried to find something similar to `HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders`, but it seems it's impossible to use this functionality in `DelegatingHandler`.

Comment: Have you tried to use `HttpContext.Current` to store and retrieve authorization info?

Answer (score 1):

You get the outgoing `HttpRequestMessage` as the `request` argument. You can access all the request headers by accessing `request.Headers`.

```cs
public class MyCustomHandler : DelegatingHandler
{

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (!request.Headers.Contains("Your Header Name"))
        {
            // Do your logic for non existing header
            request.Headers.Add("Your Header Name", "Your Header Value");
        }
        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for you response! But is seems like with `request.Headers.Add("Your Header Name", "Your Header Value");` only a header in the scope of this request is setted.

Comment: Yes it is, `SendAsync` method in delegating handler is called with every request. You need a separate service that will handle the value of your header, e.g. something with Lazy initializer that will set the value on first call.